# Nginx MIME-Types not loading

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, express, nginx

I just recently started running into an error on my website where MIME Types are not loading correctly. I am using express combined with nginx on the backend. Due to the MIME Types not loading, my CSS doesn't load and I get a warning on my JavaScript file. They are all returning Content-Type "text/html". I've already tried a few solutions on here but to no avail, if anyone knows any possible solutions that'd be a great help.

Here's an old version of my node.js code:

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const fs = require("fs");

const staticDirectory = "/var/www/html";

app.all("*", (Request, Response, Next) => {
    var pathToCheck = (() => {
        if (Request.originalUrl == "/") {
            return "/index.html";
        } else {
            return Request.originalUrl;
        }
    })()

    if (fs.existsSync(staticDirectory + pathToCheck)) {
        console.log(pathToCheck)
        let testFile = String(fs.readFileSync(staticDirectory + pathToCheck));
        if (pathToCheck.endsWith(".html")) {
            Response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
        } else if (pathToCheck.endsWith(".css")) {
            Response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/css');
        } else if (pathToCheck.endsWith(".js")) {
            Response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/javascript');
        }
        Response.status(200).send(testFile);
    } else {
        Response.status(200).send("Not found!");
    }
});
```

Here's my nginx config:

```
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;

        }

        location ~ \.css {
                add_header  Content-Type    text/css;
        }

        location ~ \.js {
                add_header  Content-Type    application/x-javascript;
        }
```

Comment: what does the nodejs code have to do with nginx? how are they related in your "setup"

Comment: I've updated the question to include my nginx configuration.

Comment: you should've kept the nodejs code too ... note: if you `proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;` it's up to the code that is listening on `http://localhost:8000` to issue correct headers - not nginx - so any request that is served by the nodejs code is subject to the headers returned by thta

Comment: I attempted to provide the correct headers with Node.js before but that didn't work either, I just edited the question to show the previous code I used.

Comment: so, the nodejs is serving the js and css that gets the warning, or is it purely nginx requests that result in that warning?

Comment: by the way, I'd do `Response.status(404).send("Not found!");` not `Response.status(200).send("Not found!");`

Comment: The nodejs is serving the js and css that gets the warning.